# How to use OR between two non-numeric values?

Tags: r

here is my code :

```
m.v <- c("A", "AGG", "A" ,"G", "GA")
count <- 0
for(i in 1: 5){
  if(m.v[i] == "A"|"G"){
    count <- count+1
  }
}
```

I received the error and I know `if(m.v[i] == "A"|"G")` is not true because "A" and "G" aren't numeric values, but how can I solve this error?

Comment: You'll have to do the equality comparison separately. `m.v[i] == "A" | m.v[i] == "G"`

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah, that was my next step :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%` instead:

```
m.v <- c("A", "AGG", "A" ,"G", "GA")
count <- 0
for(i in 1: 5){
  if(m.v[i] %in% c("A", "G")){
    count <- count+1
  }
}
count
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a `for` loop:

```r
sum(m.v %in% c("A","G"))
# [1] 3
```

R really benefits from *vectorizing* calculations. In this case, R (internally) will check each of `m.v`'s values against the vector `c("A","G")`, but externally from the user perspective, we just need to worry about the vector as a whole. Without `sum`, it returns a `logical` vector:

```r
m.v %in% c("A","G")
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

With that, when we do math operations on logicals, it silently casts them as `integer`, which sum up nicely to the intended `3`.

Not every operation in R can be done as a vector-as-a-whole, but when one can do that, one benefits in both readability (subjective) and performance (relevant for larger datasets).